# VectorList class constructor

Tags: c++, class, templates

for my assignment we are making a VectorList class and I had a question about the constructor. This is the class declaration:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
template< typename NODETYPE >
class VectorList 
{
 public:
  VectorList(); // constructor
  ~VectorList(); // destructor

  void insertAtFront( const NODETYPE & );
  void insertAtBack( const NODETYPE & );
  bool removeFromFront( NODETYPE & );
  bool removeFromBack( NODETYPE & );
  bool isEmpty() const;
  void print() const;
 private:
  vector< NODETYPE > *vList;  // list data as a vector
};
```

I thought for the constructor I would use vList = new std::vector; but the assignment has this:

```
template< typename NODETYPE > 
VectorList< NODETYPE >::VectorList()  
: // Fill in the missing code 
{  
  // empty body 
}
```

So I cannot put vList = new std::vector; in the constructor body as he wants it empty. I am unsure of what to do at this point.

Comment: Try reformatting your post so that it is easier to see your code. Select the text content and click the code button in the toolbar. It is difficult to answer your question if it is hard to see your code.

Comment: Does your vList have to be a pointer to a vector?  if it's not a pointer it will get initialized automatically to an empty vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your teacher is fishing for a [constructor initializer list](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/). This lets you initialize members before the constructor is run:

```
template< typename NODETYPE > 
VectorList< NODETYPE >::VectorList()  
    : vList(new std::vector)
{
}
```

This is the standard way to initialize members since it is equivalent to initializing at declaration time for normal variables, e.g.

```
int a(3);    // Calls int constructor with 3. Note int a = 3; does same (no call to operator=)
```

If you had a *class member* variable declared as `int a;`, the initialization can't be done at declaration, but putting it in the constructor runs *after* the object is already created. This is really assignment, and takes place using `operator=` instead of the object's constructor. It is equivalent to:

```
int a;    // Create an int
a = 3;    // Uses operator= to do assignment
```

Note also that you are `using namespace std;` in what I assume is a header file; this is a bad idea as it will pollute the namespace of any file that `#include`s your header, and could potentially cause name conflicts (and thus subtle errors). After removing that line you'll have to add the `std::` prefix before your `vector< NODETYPE >` declaration.

Finally, in the code you've posted so far, there's no need to allocate `vList` on the heap (with new) when you can have a regular vector object as a member variable:

```
vector< NODETYPE > vList;
```

This would simplify your code and reduce the possibility of introducing subtle memory-management bugs. You wouldn't need your initializer list anymore, and the destructor would also have nothing to do. Additionally, you wouldn't have to worry about defining a custom copy-constructor and assignment operator to make copy and assignment safe/work properly.